# WiX Burn: Create custom log file name for MsiPackage?

Tags: wix, installation, burn

When Burn runs an MSI installer, using MsiPackage, I'd like the MSI's log file to have a custom name, like MyProductName.log. I'd also like to append to an existing log file (with same name).

In InstallShield's Basic MSI Project's Release view there is an entry "MSI Command-Line Arguments" where you can enter a custom log file name:

/l+* "%TEMP%\MyProductName.log"

The "+" will append the log to an existing file.

Burn can pass public properties to the MSI, but I don't see a way to do what I want.

It looks like I'll need to write code (custom Burn bootstrapper) to run after the MsiPackage is installed (or uninstalled) to copy the contents of the log file (in the Burn variable defined in LogPathVariable) to the file with the custom name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the LogPathVariable attribute of the MsiPackage element to provide a custom log file name ...

See: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/msipackage.html

Also: https://support.firegiant.com/hc/en-us/articles/230912207-Pass-Properties-to-MsiPackage-from-Bundle-

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry I didn't reply sooner. I ended up writing my own bootstrapper to do what I needed.

I did try using LogPathVariable, but Burn overwrites what I set for the value.

Passing properties doesn't help for my case since I want to set the log file, which can't be set using a property.

If I missed something, please give an example of what would work.

Answer (score -1):

To do what I needed, I wrote a simple bootstrapper, which became more complicated as I addressed things like passing installer properties to the bootstrapper, giving warnings if installing an x86 installer on an x64 OS (we encourage customers to use and x64 installer), etc.

Comment: I would like to see comments from the down voters explaining their down vote. I tried the suggestions above and they didn't work, and I asked for examples that have been tried and work.

I did use the Log element in the Bundle to set a prefix, which is the best I've been able to do, but new log files are generated each time (with date and times in the name) and there is a log file for the bundle as well as the MSI. I'll see if support, marketing, and the product developers are okay with the change.